# Write DataFrame to excel along with the axis name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a dataframe along with the axis name to an excel file.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'350p HP': [7844, 2, 1],
                'tc206':[1721.5, 0.44, 1.81],
                'tcs208':[77.52, 0.02, 0.11], 
                'sas22':[1330.8, 0.34, 0.58],
                'tss21':[3070.2, 0.78, 0.56],
                'tas22': [5619.2, 1.43, 1.03]}, index=['DP', 'DP/REP', 'AF'])
df.rename_axis('col name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

here is the dataframe I'm trying to write with the axis name `col name`. I tried with both `engine='openpyxl'` and `engine='xlsxwriter'`.

```
`excel_file = "test.xlsx"
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='axisname')
 writer.save()`
```

I prefer to make it work with xlsxwriter as there are other dependencies. I'm trying to find a solution for this. Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `df.columns.name` to parameter `index_label`:

```
 df.to_excel(writer, index_label=df.columns.name)
```

Comment: Thanks. Guess I've to read the documentation more carefully

Answer (score 2):

Use `index_label`:

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

> **index_label**
> Column label for index column(s) if desired. If not specified, and header and index are True, then the index names are used. A sequence should be given if the DataFrame uses MultiIndex.

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index_label='col name')
```

Comment: Awesome. This way I don't need to make any changes to the dataframe as well. Thanks.

Comment: Right. You can just set the index label only when you write to excel file.